# How do I get bash completion for command aliases?

Tags: bash, alias, autocomplete

I am looking to get tab-completion on my command line aliases, for example, say I defined the following alias :

```
alias apt-inst='sudo aptitude install'
```

Is there a way to get the completions provided by aptitude when I hit the tab key? i.e. when I write 'sudo aptitude install gnumer' and hit tab, aptitude completes this to gnumeric, or if there was uncertainty lists all the available packages starting with gnumer. If I do it using my alias, nothing - no completion.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases/1793178

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is [a great thread about this on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=733397). Ole J proposes the following alias completion definition function:

```
function make-completion-wrapper () {
  local function_name="$2"
  local arg_count=$(($#-3))
  local comp_function_name="$1"
  shift 2
  local function="
    function $function_name {
      ((COMP_CWORD+=$arg_count))
      # Quotes here are important
      COMP_WORDS=( "$@" \"\${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}\" )
      "$comp_function_name"
      return 0
    }"
  eval "$function"
  echo $function_name
  echo "$function"
}
```

Use it to define a completion function for your alias, then specify that function as a completer for the alias:

```
make-completion-wrapper _apt_get _apt_get_install apt-get install
complete -F _apt_get_install apt-inst
```

I prefer to use aliases for adding always-used arguments to existing programs. For instance, with `grep`, I always want to skip devices and binary files, so I make an alias for `grep`. For adding new commands such as `grepbin`, I use a shell script in my `~/bin` folder. If that folder is in your path, it will get autocompleted.

Comment: Awesome, I was afraid it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: **Note** this code has some issues. See my answer for their explanation and resolution.

Comment: **Note:** I was using this technique for another command, and I had to use `complete -o default -F ...` instead of `complete -F ...` to get things like filename auto-completion working correctly when passing args (Bash 4.3.46).

Comment: I am struggling to get this working for `kubectl`. Here is what I am trying: `alias ks=kubectl\ --context=staging`; `make-completion-wrapper __start_kubectl _ks kubectl --context=staging`; ` complete -F _ks ks`; when I type `ks g` it correctly completes to `ks get` but then when i type `ks get p` I don't get expected completions like 'pods`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [update]: I think the underlying problem for me is w kubectl, not the alias... `kubectl get p` also does not complete as expected.

Comment: In your code snippet, what is `_apt_get` referring to? Is that supposed to be an existing function?

Comment: This fails for me when creating a wrapper for `alias nr="npm run"`. I tracked it down to missing quotes around `\${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}`, which results in `COMP_WORDS=([0]="npm" [1]="run")` instead of `COMP_WORDS=([0]="npm" [1]="run" [2]="")`, which breaks npm's completion script.

Answer (score 101):

Try [complete-alias](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias), which solves this problem exactly. (*Disclaimer*: I am the author of `complete_alias`)

After install it you can use one generic function to complete many aliases like this:

```
complete -F _complete_alias <myalias1>
complete -F _complete_alias <myalias2>
complete -F _complete_alias <myalias3>
```

---

You may want to source the `complete_alias` file in every bash instance through `.bash_profile` or similar.

#### installation

```
mkdir ~/.bash_completion.d
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cykerway/complete-alias/master/complete_alias \
     > ~/.bash_completion.d/complete_alias
```

#### application

```
source ~/.bash_completion.d/complete_alias

alias container=docker\ container
complete -F _complete_alias container
```

`container` can now be autocompleted by the original `_docker()` completion handler;

```
$ container l<Tab>
logs  ls    

$ container s<Tab>
start  stats  stop
```

Comment: Given that this software seems to be yours, you could do better than this. Add instructions on installing it. Describe what it does and how to use it. Otherwise this is just spam.

Comment: @muru I was thinking of pasting some code here but it's probably longer than accepted here. I'd assume people have no problem reading the *Install* section in a README file, and in this case it's only several lines.

Comment: the point is to be able to judge whether visiting said README is worthwhile, just from the answer.

Comment: This is an adequate answer and it solves the problem exactly.

Comment: This is an excellent and very comprehensive answer that works perfectly, thanks!. It's probably been updated since @muru had problems with it.

Comment: @Cyker I really want to use your script since it'd make the completion process so clean, but I keep getting the following errors: `_completion_loader: command not found` and `_command_offset: command not found`

Any ideas what could be wrong? I already had bash-completion installed on my system (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @J-Win That looks like `bash-completion` is not correctly installed, or properly sourced in your current shell environment. Both `_completion_loader` and `_command_offset` are functions defined by `bash-completion`. If you installed and sourced it properly, you should be able to get some meaningful output when running `declare -f _completion_loader` and `declare -f _command_offset`. You may want to check your `bash_profile` and `bashrc` files in both system and user configurations.

Comment: @Cyker so on my WSL setup it worked just fine, but on my actual Ubuntu setup I had to first source the bash_completion script by doing `source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`. Either way it works great now so thanks for the help!

Comment: Found it a little confusing until i checked the Readme.md and relased that to keep the specific alias completion one needs to add the `complete -F _complete_alias myAlias` to a `~/.bash_completion` (or create one if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Just un-comment the last line of bash_completion to enable autocomplete of all aliases :) Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

By googling this issue I ended up here, so I tried the approaches in the other answers. For various reasons I don't actually understand, they never behaved properly in my Ubuntu 16.04.

What in the end worked for me was way more trivial than expected. I wanted to use the same autocompletion as `rsync` has for `mycommand`. Hence, I looked up the autocompletion function, and then called `complete` accordingly.

```
# Lookup of name of autocompletion function used for rsync
_completion_loader rsync; complete -p rsync
# Returns: complete -o nospace -F _rsync rsync

# Sourcing the rsync functions before, then using the same function for 'mycommand'
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/rsync
complete -o nospace -F _rsync mycommand
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure what's the downside of my approach compared to the others. I mainly wrote this as it could help people where this trivial approach might be enough.

Comment: It seems that bash says `bash: complete: XYZ: no completion specification` until you actually try to complete with `XYZ` the first time. I think editing the user `.bash_completion` file is the way to go, though I'm still not sure how...

Comment: Turns out that the way to do this is call `_completion_loader rsync` first, to make sure the completion function is loaded. It is sometimes (always?) loaded only when you try to autocomplete with the function for the first time. This answer also has another problem: it cannot autocomplete with the context of arguments provided. E.g. it cannot make an alias for `pass -c` autocomplete like `pass -c`, only like `pass`. These are different.

Comment: what about a command with sub-command like `git checkout`?

Comment: this worked and it was quite simple. to avoid having to duplicate the `complete` options, you can print the completion dynamically like so: `$(complete -p rsync | rev | cut -d' ' -f 2- | rev) mycommand`

Comment: also, `. /usr/share/bash-completions` doesn't work if the command is installed locally (e.g. ~/.local/bin or /usr/local/share). instead try `__load_completion rsync` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544119)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code from [Shawn J. Goff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4220/143394) with some improvements:

- Fixed syntax errors highlighted by [`shell-check`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), eg the first `"` of `"$@"` actually *ended* the function definition string.
- Removed the `return 0` so that the return value of the underlying function can be passed back to the caller.

.

```
# Wraps a completion function, eg for use with an alias.
# Usage:
# make-completion-wrapper <actual completion function> <name of new func.>
#                         <command name> <list supplied arguments>
# eg.
#   alias agi='apt-get install'
#   make-completion-wrapper _apt_get _apt_get_install apt-get install
#     # defines a function called _apt_get_install (that's $2) that will
#     # complete the 'agi' alias. 
#   complete -F _apt_get_install agi
function make-completion-wrapper {
  local function_name="$2"
  local arg_count=$(( $#-3 ))
  local comp_function_name="$1"
  shift 2
  local function="function $function_name {
      (( COMP_CWORD += $arg_count ))
      COMP_WORDS=( \"\$@\" \${COMP_WORDS[@]:1} )
      \"$comp_function_name\"
    }"
  eval "$function"
  # echo "$function"
}
export -f make-completion-wrapper
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Bash 4.3.46 I'm afraid. Shaun J. Goff's answer _does_ work.

Comment: "Ending" the function definition string is on purpose; the point is to include arguments from the outer function into the `COMP_WORDS` array. If we use `make-completion-wrapper _apt_get _apt_get_install apt-get install` as an example, after `shift 2`, `$@` contains `apt-get install`. The function definition includes `apt-get install` (the two literal words) when assigning `COMP_WORDS`.

Answer (score 3):

**2018 answer**

You must add your alias to the program 'complete'. Depending the kind of autocompletion you want to achieve, you must use -c or -F.

For package autocompletion:

```
complete -c name_of_your_alias
```

For command autocompletion:

```
complete -F name_of_your_alias
```

To check if your alias was added correctly:

```
complete | grep name_of_your_alias
```

Finally, to remove an alias from 'complete':

```
complete -r name_of_your_alias
```

**In your case:**

```
complete -c apt-inst
```

Comment: Please don’t continue your answer in comments. If you have things to say, [edit] them into the answer.

Comment: `complete -F xxx` does not work on OSX (It just shows the usage `complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]`) . Do you have any pointer? Thanks.

Comment: Use this instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224227/how-do-you-make-an-alias-or-function-that-retains-tab-completion

Comment: This is great information except for not resolving the situation asked in the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to @Giles answer, the following convenience function auto-names the wrapper generated by `make-completion-wrapper` to make it possible to define completion in one line:

```
function complete-alias  {
    # uses make-completion-wrapper: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4220/50978
    # example usage
    # complete-alias _pass pshow pass show
    # complete-alias _pass pgen pass generate

    EXISTING_COMPLETION_FN=${1} && shift
    ALIAS=${1} && shift
    AUTOGEN_COMPLETION_FN="__autogen_completion_${ALIAS}"
    make-completion-wrapper ${EXISTING_COMPLETION_FN} ${AUTOGEN_COMPLETION_FN} ${*}
    complete -F ${AUTOGEN_COMPLETION_FN} ${ALIAS}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Own local completions may be defined in `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions` as explained in the [bash-completion FAQs](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md)

A simple approach is thus to create this directory (if not existing) and put a file named `mycommand` (with `alias mycommand='realcommand'` as the alias definition) and to just a) source the original command's completion and b) refer to the function in `complete`, e.g.:

```
$cat  ~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/mycommand

source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/realcommand
complete -F _realcommand mycommand
```

If the function is called `_realcommand`. Use completion on `realcommand` and then `complete -p | grep realcommand` to see how the function is actually called.

If the alias is meant to be system-wide, one may as well place the file in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` directly.

**Limitations**

1. Needs manually adding the entry for each alias, not automated.
2. Fails if the completion function refers to the command itself:

It worked nicely for e.g. `alias userctl='systemctl --user'`, it (partly) failed for `alias mylsblk=lsblk` when tab-completing anything other than `mylsblk -<TAB>`. This is due to the function `_lsblk_module` referring to the command name (via `$1`) in the completion script and this fails as  `mylsblk` cannot be found as command. It worked, when I replaced `$1` with `lsblk` in the completion script of `lsblk` (**not recommended**, done for testing purposes only).

In this case, the local completion script has to be slightly adapted so that the first argument remains the command name:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/lsblk
_lsblk_dummy() { _lsblk_module lsblk ; }
complete -F _lsblk_dummy mylsblk
```

which might as well be seen as general approach.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Works for me with an alias from `docker` to just the character `d`. The alias gets completion even on `docker` CLI sub-commands like `d create `. Just press "TAB"! My installation notes here: https://github.com/dgroomes/my-config/commit/81560949cc6b6d354fd6584c9a290c1a1581a020#diff-c27c113aeeeca3dab7b6c2a3d48bfcd247e13e2fc2f5aba8917750f0170a7ee4R159

Comment: I used /etc/bash_completion.d/ in Debian bullseye with kubectl. I added the kubectl comletions there and also the alias file k sourcing kubectl. Both in the same dir.  `complete -p | grep kubectl` was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution; in my case I aliased `k` to `kubectl`, and wanted to have bash completion for the `k` alias as well:

1. Make sure the `bash-completion` package is installed (that's the correct package name on Debian/Ubuntu/RHEL; it might be different on other distributions).
2. Create a file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/k` with the following content:

   ```
   # Load completion for the kubectl command:
   . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/kubectl

   # Get the completion definition for kubectl (in the form of "complete ... kubectl"):
   __k_kubectl_comp=$(complete -p kubectl)

   # Transform "complete ... kubectl" into "complete ... k" by replacing the last
   # word, and eval the result:
   eval "${__k_kubectl_comp% *} k"

   # That's it, clean up!
   unset __k_kubectl_comp
   ```
3. Now the `k` alias should have the same completion as the `kubectl` command (you might have to open a new shell first).

This will essentially retrieve the `complete` command for `kubectl`, modify it so that it applies to the `k` alias, and run the resulting command. For example, `complete -p kubectl` on my system prints:

```
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl kubectl
```

The shell script above will transform this to `complete -o default -F __start_kubectl k`, and run that command.

**Footnote:** The directory to drop bash completion code snippets into is not necessarily always `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`. You can get the directory that your system uses by running `pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion` (see also the [README of the `bash-completion` package](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/2.1/README#L113)).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that a few responses are concerned with autocompleting with `kubectl` aliases. While other answers have addressed how to have auto complete on an alias for `kubectl`, they will not work when you have an alias for something like `kubectl describe pod`. I believe this is related to how `kubectl` does completion and not about completion in general.

#### Alias completion for kubectl version 1.27.1

Putting the following in my `.bash_profile` works to get multiword `kubectl` aliases working for v1.27.1:

```bash
# Load kubectl completion functions
# Need to run:
#    kubectl completion bash > ~/.kubectl-completion
# To generate the .kubectl-completion file
source ~/.kubectl-completion

# Create the pod-show alias
alias pod-show="kubectl describe pod"

# Modified from the accepted answer
__start_kubectl_pods() {
  local compl
  compl=${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}
  (( COMP_CWORD += 2 ))
  COMP_WORDS=( kubectl describe pod "${compl:- }" )
  __start_kubectl
}

# Setup completion
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl_pods pod-show
```

A couple of notes:

- the `__start_kubectl` is the main function for completing `kubectl` commmands. This function requires a space at the end to do completion on no arguments. I believe this is why the accepted answer does not work out of the box.
- Running `export BASH_COMP_DEBUG_FILE=compdebug` and then trying the completion outputs debug logs to a file named compdebug. This helped with figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is close but fails with some completion functions (e.g. completing an alias for `npm run`) due to quoting issues within its call to `eval`.

Here's a solution that builds on Shawn Goff's and user84207's answers, with the following improvements:

- Fixes quoting issues
- Fixes shellcheck warnings
- Puts the minimal amount of logic inside `eval` so the code is easier to reason about (and can be checked with shellcheck).

```bash
# Adapted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531400/10183
# Example usage: complete-alias _pass pgen pass generate
complete_alias() {
  local old_completion_fn="$1" && shift
  local alias_name="$1" && shift
  local new_completion_fn="_alias_completion__${alias_name}"
  bind_function "$new_completion_fn" alias_completion_wrapper "$old_completion_fn" "$alias_name" "$@"
  complete -o default -F "$new_completion_fn" "$alias_name"
}

# Adapted from:
# - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4220/50978
# - https://superuser.com/a/437508/56109
alias_completion_wrapper() {
  local old_completion_fn="$1" && shift
  local alias_name="$1" && shift
  local alias_command=("$@")
  local arg_count=$(($# - 1))

  ((COMP_CWORD+=$arg_count))
  COMP_WORDS=( "${alias_command[@]}" "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}" )
  (( COMP_POINT -= ${#COMP_LINE} ))
  COMP_LINE=${COMP_LINE/#$alias_name/${alias_command[@]}}
  (( COMP_POINT += ${#COMP_LINE} ))
  $old_completion_fn
}

# Creates a new function with the given name (arg 1) that calls the given
# source function (arg 2) with the given arguments (remaining args).
bind_function() {
  local dest_fn src_fn bind_args
  printf -v dest_fn "%q" "$1" && shift
  printf -v src_fn "%q" "$1" && shift
  printf -v bind_args "%q " "$@"
  eval "function $dest_fn() { $src_fn $bind_args; }"
}
```