# Forward Autocorrect to a script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get bash completion for command aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-for-command-aliases)

I wrote a series of scripts to make package management a little more intuitive for me. However, I can no longer tab complete for package names. Is there a way I can forward the results of a tab completion to a script?

Sample- package-install:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install $*
```

Comment: Make that `apt-get install "$@"`. `$*` breaks the arguments into words, interprets them as wildcard patterns, then stitches the pieces back together. This may produce nonsensical results if the arguments contain whitespace or wildcard characters. `"$@"` replicates the script's arguments exactly.

Comment: This is such a simple script, you could make it an alias: `alias package-install='apt-get install'` (put this line in your `~/.bashrc`). The solution for completing is the same whether you have a wrapper script or an alias.

Comment: I wanted it in a script for a couple reasons. One is that I want to distribute it via github to computers that I use in the future, and I want to add other OS's besides ubuntu. Another is that some of the scripts are more than one command, all of which require su or sudo.