# How do you make an alias or function that retains tab completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, alias

I made an alias to save some keystrokes with working with systemd:

```
$ alias sctl='systemctl'
```

However, this breaks tab completion for the subcommands. Is it possible to alias a command without breaking tab completion?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First find out which complete-function is used for the `systemctl` command:

```
complete | grep " systemctl$"
```

The output looks like this:

```
complete -F _functionname systemctl
```

Then use:

```
complete -F _functionname sctl
```

To register the function for the completion of your alias.

Now, when you type `sctl <tab><tab>`, the same suggestions as when you type `systemctl` will appear.

Comment: As extra note: Use -c instead of -F if you need package autocompletion for your alias.

Comment: Note this only works for autocompletion on the command itself, not on the command + args. Eg if you `alias='command arg1 arg2'` then the above will produce completion as though you had just typed `command`, not `command arg1 arg2`.

Comment: This was giving me ``bash: completion: function `_systemctl' not found`` when typing `sctl <tab><tab>`. I fixed this by adding `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl`, which defines the function, before `complete -F _systemctl sctl`.

Comment: about loading completion functions, `_completion_loader <commandname>` is sometimes the best way for that.  I wanted to note that this answer doesn't always work. I found some completions that depend on `_parse_help`, they call help on the command itself. and in that context the alias apparently does not exist, so no help-derived completions work.

Comment: @creanion Aliases don't work with `_parse_help` but shell functions should.

Answer (score 5):

After installing [this tool](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias), you can do it like this:

- In `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  alias sctl='systemctl'
  ```
- In `~/.bash_completion`:

  ```
  complete -F _complete_alias sctl
  ```
- Type `sctl <tab>` to show `systemctl` commands:

  ```
  $ sctl <Tab>
  add-requires
  add-wants
  cancel
  cat
  condreload
  ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I hacked this to have completion also work for systemctl+args. I copied some parts of the source code of bash-completion for systemctl to manage that (/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl).

```
alias ssr='sudo systemctl restart'
alias sss='sudo systemctl status'
alias ssp='sudo systemctl stop'

# Load necessary functions in bash-completion's source code for systemctl (get_*_units)
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl
# Manually recreate some functions
_systemctl_status()
{
        comps=$( __get_non_template_units --system "${COMP_WORDS[1]}" )
        compopt -o filenames
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o filenames -W '$comps') )
        return 0
}

_systemctl_restart()
{
        comps=$( __get_restartable_units --system "${COMP_WORDS[1]}" )
        compopt -o filenames
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o filenames -W '$comps') )
        return 0
}

_systemctl_stop()
{
        comps=$( __get_stoppable_units --system "${COMP_WORDS[1]}" )
        compopt -o filenames
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o filenames -W '$comps') )
        return 0
}

complete -F _systemctl_restart ssr
complete -F _systemctl_status sss
complete -F _systemctl_stop ssp
```

This can easily be expanded for other systemctl commands, just look for the right get_*_units command in the source file and copy my examples.

I also tried to modify the $COMP_WORDS array to get some general solution working for all commands, but to no avail.