# xdg-open autocomplete not working when calling it with alias

Tags: bash, alias, xdg-open

I've set an alias to xdg-open adding `alias op="xdg-open"` to my `~/.bashrc` file.

The command `op file.pdf` works, but I'm not able to autocomplete when typing, for example, `op fi` and hitting TAB.

This is kind of annoying as the point of setting the alias is to save time. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get bash completion for command aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-for-command-aliases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) installed, which automatically loads the completion it ships [for the `op` command](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/op) when you try to complete a command line starting with your `op` alias.

You can avoid this by:

- Choosing a different alias (and looking at the files in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` to make sure you pick a safe name); or
- Adding `complete -o default -o bashdefault op` to your `~/.bashrc` to instruct bash-completion not to use the shipped completion (see "How can I override a completion shipped by bash-completion?" in the FAQ at the GitHub repository linked above).

  Of course, if you are defining an alias to a command for which a completion file exists on your system, you may use the completion function defined there instead of resetting the completion to its default behavior. Note, though, that this would probably require you to explicitly load the completion function. The resulting `.bashrc` snippet could be:

  ```bash
  alias your_alias=aliased_command
  _completion_loader aliased_command
  complete -F completion_function your_alias
  ```